# Scons files not recognised as Python but as conf

Tags: neovim, filetype

Neovim assigns a file type of "conf" to SConscruct and SConscript files -- aka the scons configuration scripts. This is wrong. It should be Python.

I tried adding: `au BufNewFile,BufRead SCons* setf python` to my `~/.config/nvim/init.vim` yet the file type remains set at "conf".

I did try it on vim and it worked fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [Issue 8130](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/8130)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of problems here.

Firstly, you are using the `:setfiletype` command, which only sets the `'filetype'` if it has not already been set. (See [`:help :setfiletype`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%3Asetfiletype).)

If you change your autocommand to set the `'filetype'` directly with `:set filetype=python`, this will result in the `python` filetype being used, as you desire.

However, this still isn't perfect, because now Vim is first setting the `'filetype'` to `conf` (based on its contents) and then *changing* it to `python`, and it's possible that some options are set for `conf` files that you do not want in `python` files.

To avoid this, follow the instructions in section **C** of [`:help new-filetype`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/filetype.txt.html#new-filetype) to detect this filetype *before* the installed detection runs by creating a `.vim/filetype.vim` file with the following contents:

```
" my filetype file
if exists("did_load_filetypes")
  finish
endif
augroup filetypedetect
  autocmd! BufRead,BufNewFile SCons* setfiletype python
augroup END
```

I'd also note that it's not really a *bug* that Vim is using a `'filetype'` of `conf` here. Vim's runtime files set a large number of types automatically, but they cannot automatically set the types of *all* files, now and in the future. This is why the mechanisms described in the documentation linked to above exist: to allow you to add `filetype` detection for currently unsupported files as necessary.

It is of course, reasonable to suggest that it be added as a feature request: hopefully automatic detection of SCons files will be added in future versions!

Answer (score 1):

Put a file this content into your `.vim/ftdetect` folder, I name it scons.vim:

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile SCons{truct,cript} set filetype=python
```

https://bitbucket.org/plunket/dotfiles/src/1dc45bcec068220b7df2079b9c1e3b07fd76048f/vim/ftdetect/scons.vim?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default

Comment: Note that this will still result in the file first being set to have a type of `conf`, as I described in my answer. See Section **A** of `:help new-filetype`

Comment: It's less typing and more modular, which are preferences for me! ;-)